# code works on http://jsfiddle.net but not working on http://liveweave.com

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, jsfiddle

i've a google-map application which draws a line-path in google map, the code that works perfectly in http://jsfiddle.net but does not seems working on http://liveweave.com

The working code in jsfiddle is as shown below.

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/vPzPj/2/)

**[LIVEWEAVE](http://liveweave.com/cmDd3f)**

This is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
    #map_canvas {
    width:550px;
    height:400px;
}
</style>

<link href="http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/standard.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
       function initialize(){
       var center= new google.maps.LatLng(10.012552,76.327043);
       var myOptions = {
                zoom: 16,
                center: center,
                mapTypeControl: true,
                mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU},
                navigationControl: true,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
       }     
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

      var polylineCoordinates = [
            new google.maps.LatLng(10.013566,76.331549),
            new google.maps.LatLng(10.013566,76.331463),
            new google.maps.LatLng(10.013503,76.331313),
            new google.maps.LatLng(10.013482,76.331205),
            new google.maps.LatLng(10.013419,76.330926),
            new google.maps.LatLng(10.013334,76.330712),
            new google.maps.LatLng(10.013313,76.330411),
            new google.maps.LatLng(10.013292,76.330175),
            new google.maps.LatLng(10.013228,76.329854),
            new google.maps.LatLng(10.013144,76.329553),
            new google.maps.LatLng(10.013059,76.329296),
            new google.maps.LatLng(10.012996,76.329017),
            new google.maps.LatLng(10.012869,76.328802),
            new google.maps.LatLng(10.012785,76.328545),
            new google.maps.LatLng(10.012700,76.328223),
            new google.maps.LatLng(10.012679,76.328030),
            new google.maps.LatLng(10.012658,76.327837),
            new google.maps.LatLng(10.012637,76.327600),
            new google.maps.LatLng(10.012573,76.327322),
            new google.maps.LatLng(10.012552,76.327043),
            new google.maps.LatLng(10.012552,76.326807),
            new google.maps.LatLng(10.012510,76.326613),
            new google.maps.LatLng(10.012447,76.326399),
            new google.maps.LatLng(10.012404,76.326227),
      ];

            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(10.012404,76.32622),
            icon: {
                path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
                scale: 3.5,
                strokeColor: '#FF3300'   
            },
            draggable: true,
            map: map
            });          
      var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
          path: polylineCoordinates,
          strokeColor: '#5C5CE6',
          strokeOpacity: 2.0,
          strokeWeight: 5,
          editable: false
      });

      polyline.setMap(map);    

}
initialize();

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="map_canvas" ></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because of the way the script is being executed.  Jsfiddle has the setting onDomready set so it will execute the javascript when the dom has loaded.  I do not see a similar option in liveweave.

instead of placing `initialize();` at the end of the script add the function to the body tags onload attribute.

`<body onload="initialize();">`

Example:  http://liveweave.com/Dj5fSM